# What is the best way to crop an image in HTML?

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to crop an image in HTML?

It would be something like the following:

```
<img src="something.gif" x1="10" y1="10" x2="20" y2="20">
```

If that doesn't work, then I'll just use GIMP.  Any thoughts on how I can get this to work programmatically?

Comment: Way to go champ, not only are you harassing users by mass-editing their posts, you're reverting legitimate fixes now!

Comment: I agree. GK, please cut this out now.

Comment: @Rich B: I believe he's talking about you.  "What is a fastest way" was your rollback from the correct "What is the fastest way".

Comment: @James: Yes I am aware. Mistakes happen, and it got fixed. Ant P is just bringing his flamewars to new threads, it is ok. I was working with the OP to get the post all set up.

Comment: @All I originaly asked "a fast way". As i had no clue how to do this. How it is now it's good. Thank you for your willingness to help my questions you even turned it into community wiki. If you all focused more on helping ppl find solutions it would me much better for everyone

Comment: How it is now it's good == As it is now it's good. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @fmsf: I agree, if we could stop having these rollback wars and let the mods do their jobs, people like you would benefit greatly from better editing in your posts.

Comment: Bloddy 'ell people LET IT GO!

Comment: @Darko: Good timing a few days late.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527336/tools-to-make-css-sprites

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's called sprites, you can read this fantastic article of [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/).

In the end it boils down to:

```
#panel2b {
    width:50px;
    height:30px;
    background: transparent url(test-3.jpg) -96px -200px no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: You need a height & width definition for that panel for it to work.

Comment: Ahhh sprites, reminds me the good days when I painted sprites in C64 with bytes representation...

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a tool like [this web based CSS Sprite Generator](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/) to create a larger image if you have many slices.

[Someone on [my similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527336) led me to yours].