# Tools to make CSS sprites?

Tags: css, css-sprites, web-performance

Are there any good tools to make css sprites?

IDEALLY I'd want to give it a directory of images and an existing .css file that refers to those images and have it create a big image optimized with all the little images AND change my .css file to refer to those images.

At the least I'd want it to take a directory of images and generate a big sprite and the .css necessary to use each as a background.

Are there any good photoshop plugins or fully blown apps to do this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519774/searching-for-a-direct-way-to-load-a-slice-of-a-gif-png-jpg-into-an-html

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more, are you trying to compile all the sprites on one larger image and then use css to display the part of the image that contains the right sprite. (sliding doors technique)

Comment: check also this: http://spritepad.wearekiss.com/ ;)

Comment: is there a way to change the background color so I can see my white icons on spritepad?

Comment: I wrote an example for you, just format the printf for your css (different people use different methods, so I just used an output that is easily parseble - feel free to change it) http://stackoverflow.com/a/13281578/1162141

Comment: Partick, shouldnt your comment be an independent answer?

Comment: I really don't understand why this was closed?? There seems to be lots of good useful answers. This arguably should be a Superuser question because I don't mention any particular programming language but I like the answers I got and they've obviously been useful to many.

Comment: Please god do not delete this question, it is the most helpful list on the internet for this problem, and is certainly related to programming *(even if it's not a programming question per-say)*.  This is definitely a judgement-call, and should **not** have been force-closed by the mods; that is what the community vote-closing system is for....

Comment: I'm a big fan of glue. http://glue.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ It works on Windows, OSX, and Ubuntu/Debian.

Comment: adobe fireworks, although deprecated is a good piece of software for making sprites.  no complaints.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This will do 90% of the work for you: [CSS Sprite Generator](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/). You'll still need to edit the rules yourself, but the tool will give you the code fragments you need for the new CSS file.

Comment: @ben perfect! assuming it works ;-)

Comment: i'm a little dissatisfied with this tool so i unchose it as my selected answer. it ended up cropping my image and it doesnt explain very well why it leaves big gaps between images

Comment: I don't like this solution, although I guess it works ok. SpriteMe seems to work much better.

Comment: the problem with this tool is that the images aren't at full quality.

Answer (score 50):

[Instant Sprite](http://instantsprite.com) is an in-browser CSS sprite generator I'm working on.  It's really fast, but doesn't have quite as many features as some of the others.  It currently only works in Firefox or Chrome, since it uses JavaScript FileReader and HTML Canvas to generate the sprites inside the web browser without uploads.

Comment: I've used your tool to work on some production web sites since you've posted here.  It's very simple and easy.

Comment: Daniel, great to hear that you have been using it!! I use it all the time, and I'm glad that others are get some benefit from it too.

Comment: +1.  Your tool is far better than the rest I've tried.

Comment: this is the most intuitive one yet... thanks... (although, it should include the "smart" layout of sprites to minimize performance issues)

Comment: Thanks everyone!  @Harsh, I agree about the layout - I started experimenting with that quite a while ago but never quite got it working: https://github.com/bgrins/InstantSprite/tree/bin-pack

Comment: THIS IS THE BEST SPRITE TOOL I've used!

Comment: Thank you very much for this tool. This was just pleasant to use.

Comment: Great job. Some feedback: 1) In the output CSS, replace `0px` with `0` to save a few chars. 2) If most input images have the same size, move those dimensions into the top-level CSS rule and only override as needed (I have three from 250 which are slightly different). 3) Remove the extra whitespace before the closing `}` brace. 4) Did I mention this is a great site?

Comment: @DrewNoakes Thanks for the feedback :).  I haven't been doing a lot of work on it lately but it is all open source: https://github.com/bgrins/InstantSprite so if anyone wants to help out with some of these it'd be awesome.  I think 1 and 3 would be pretty easy fixes.  As for 2: Dimensions are defined globally here: https://github.com/bgrins/InstantSprite/blob/1ced360acbd312557c8849b465e580b2d6c0a1f5/site/scripts/instantsprite.js#L253.  I think it'd be possible to change this to instead see if > 50% or 75% of them use the same dimension to predefine as you suggest and override others.

Comment: @BrianGrinstead, just submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/bgrins/InstantSprite/pull/9) that covers these features. Ended up deciding that the test for reusing dimensions should just assess whether more than one images shares a size. Tested locally and all seems well.

Answer (score 31):

There is now Sprite Me by Steve Souders. Just tries it out and it seems to work pretty well.

Here is the link http://spriteme.org/ and here is the blog post announcing it.

http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/09/14/spriteme/

Comment: +1 This is amazingly easy to use: Just navigate to the page you want and click the SpriteMe bookmarklet... It creates the images and CSS automatically!

Comment: It's a nice tool, but, it requires a ZIP file of your images and the order it puts your sprites in is the ZIP order.  Brian's tool below allows you to upload files and drag&drop to change order.

Comment: I like that it has source code freely available

Answer (score 13):

This looks promising :

http://csssprites.org/

Also i found [this article](http://mezzoblue.com/archives/2009/01/27/sprite_optim/) which has some useful information, and even some reader comments worth reading.

Also apparently google web toolkit has something - so if you're using that it might be worth checking out.

Comment: Seems like the page doesn't work anymore...

Comment: http://smartsprites.osinski.name/ was renamed http://csssprites.org/, so I edited it for you. It seems to be the one of the few options that can be integrated into the build process, from what I've seen here.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

http://spritepad.wearekiss.com/

Comment: This is definitely legitimate. Saved spritemaps IMHO are a key, so only relevant images and lines of code would have to change over time, instead of recalculating the whole coordinate set with every image content change.

Answer (score 7):

[ZeroSprites](http://zerosprites.com/) is a CSS sprites generator aimed at area minimization using VLSI floorplaning algorithms.

Answer (score 6):

[found this one pretty fast](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/section/tool-help) tho that 500K upload limit might be a pain. source code is available [here](https://launchpad.net/css-sprite-generator/)

Comment: why would 500kb upload be a pain? i'd probably never want to upload > 100kb

Comment: I said it 'might' be a pain. It sorta depends on the application no ? .. A zip file full of medium size PNGs, for example,  on a sizable grid ~ ~could~ run close to this number. if its all little bitmaps then sure/ no prob.

Comment: ya but the whole point of css sprites is to prevent lots of little images being loaded with many requests. if you really did have that many little sprites it would take a long time to load in which time none would be displayed. best to keep them i'd think at most 100kb. you can always do several

Comment: i do a lot of work with images. maybe not little css bitmaps. so maybe that's why i gave the caveat. your needs are different/ ok. 500kb will arrive in a second on most broadbands. i was first to supply the accepted answer to your query and here i am down~voted and defending my language? whatever...

Comment: It was a pain for me, since the images that I started with ended up being a bundle greater in size than that limit, so I had to cut out or optimize before I could even use it.

Answer (score 4):

[Tonttu](http://collamo.jp/Tonttu/)  is Adobe AIR based application which provides easy interface for creating powerful CSS Sprites images. You can specify FiledWidth and FieldHeight or sort images.
[Create CSS Sprites Images with Tonttu Desktop Tool](http://www.blogsdna.com/5375/create-css-sprites-images-with-tonttu-desktop-tools.htm)

Answer (score 4):

Not clear yet if it'll make it into the core ASP.NET framework but here's a Microsoft codeplex project for csssprites :

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/50869

if you like it - use it - or just like the idea then add a comment. I think this would be a great thing to have in the ASP.NET framework. Have not personally used it (I had to invent the wheel myself) but its got good reviews.

---

It includes the following components:

- API for automatically generating sprites and inline images
- Controls and helpers which provide a convenient way of calling into the API

Features Added in Second Release:

- A CSS linking control for Web Forms (selects the proper CSS file for the user's browser, but does not display an image)
- Using custom folder paths other than App_Sprites
- Changing the tiling direction of sprite images
- Merging the generated CSS with a user's own CSS

Features under consideration for future releases:

- Automatically selecting the most efficient sprite background colour
- Automatically minifying the rendered CSS
- Compiling against .NET 3.5

Answer (score 4):

Just use http://sprites.scherpontwikkeling.nl/ it can generate sprites from website URL's as well...you can integrate your sprites after developing your website. It's very easy to use ;)

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer but to my fellow developers and web integrators, consider simply aligning each sprite to powers of two; eg a 16 pixel or 32 pixel grid. It makes calculating offsets in the CSS file much easier. All the white space between does not matter as the gifd and png formats compress that very well.

Comment: good tip, although i'm mainly trying to combine text headers (1-2kb each) into a single file. i'm not worried too much about white space because i know it'll get compressed out - i just dont completely understand why tools to make sprites make so much of it

Comment: One caveat to this - while the whitespace in the image will be compressed for transport, it is expanded and occupies memory when loaded the browser. Blind use of automatic sprite generation tools can lead to some huge images, which can spike memory use on those pages. Some care is needed in grouping images to form sprite sheets to keep this within reasonable bounds.

Comment: Sam: True! Found this out later. If the sprite image is very wide or tall that's something to consider! Especially for mobile phone apps (less memory).

Simon: the white space is probably because of limitations of CSS. Even when you use no-repeat on a background, the sprite image will show through padding, line-height and basically all the element's background area except margins and borders. Say for example you have an icon for a link. If the link would span mutliple lines then other icons of the sprite might show through. Adding enough whitespace makes this more "resilient".

Comment: @Simon_Weaver - Based on everyones feedback here, I posted a sprite tool that is simple http://stackoverflow.com/a/13281578/1162141

Answer (score 3):

Compass CSS Framework has [automatic sprite generation](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/).

Comment: I'm stunned by the amount of people not using Compass for Sprite Generation. Compass was born for this...

Answer (score 2):

If you like Java, then you can use GWT 1.5+ which comes with something called "[ImageBundle](http://code.google.com/intl/en/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5&s=google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5&t=DevGuideImageBundles)." The GWT compiler will handle all the nasty details for you. You won't even have to code a single line of JavaScript or write any CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script that [combines images via a Photoshop script into CSS sprites](http://www.interactivellama.com/blog/archives/photoshop-script-combine-two-images-css-hover-css-sprite/). It won't do a sprite map as you asked, but it will combine images in multiples of two (2, 4, 8) if they are the same size. I prefer combining similar images (normal, hover, selected, parent of selected) than having all the images in one file.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using ruby on rails, there is an easy to install library to generate css sprites.

http://github.com/aberant/spittle

Answer (score 2):

There is a new tool out there called ActiveSprites, part of the active_assets gem.

Github: http://bitly.com/eRTwU4

You use a ruby dsl to define your sprites and then do "rake sprites" and the sprites and corresponding stylesheets get generated.

It's rad!

Here's some sample code,

```
# config/sprites.rb
Rails.application.sprites do
  sprite 'sprites/sprite1.png' => 'sprites/sprite1.css' do
    _'sprite_images/sprite1/1.png' => 'a.one'
    _'sprite_images/sprite1/2.png' => 'span.two'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/northpoint/SpeedySprite

This tool takes a novel approach in that it assembles your requested images on the fly as an http service.  This makes the whole process pretty simple (no preprocessing required, change images any time): You start the service and then reference whatever images you want in your HTML:

```
<link href="css/my-images-dir/" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="my-image-name-here" />
```

Because it's dynamic, you can even make sprites from a dynamic set of images such as a thumbnail page.  Doesn't support JPEG though, but PNG and GIF works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [Sprite Master Web](http://www.mobinodo.com/spritemasterweb). I generates sprite sheets automatically and exports CSS code for you. It always tries to generate smallest sprite sheets with advanced algorithms.

Here is a screenshot and [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=458Qx7JW5PI)

[image]

Comment: Worth noting, this is not a free or open source app but fairly priced at $3.99. It's well built and does good PNG compression.

Comment: Mac only. Bummer, this one looked promising.

Answer (score 1):

None of these tools met my requirements, so I wrote one that uses Mark Tylers's tiny image library, mtpixel (now part of [mtcelledit](http://code.google.com/p/mtcelledit/))
It isn't super extensive but it is easily extensible through mtpixel's built in functions that include: grayscale, color inversion, rotation, sharpen, quantize, posterize, flip (vertical and horizontal), transform, rgb->indexed, indexed->rgb, edge detect, emboss, drawing polygons, text and more.

All you do is pass it a set of images as args (supports png, gif and jpeg) and it will output an rgb png called sprite.png along with the useful image slicing data to stdout.  I use it in bash scripts to spritify an entire directory of images and output the slicing data for automatic generation of css (with the hope of eventually making it capable of replacing existing img tags automagically with a bit of creative sed/awk)

Binary packages for puppy linux will be here:

http://murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=82009

My use case only required splicing the images vertically into a new png, so that is all it does, but my source code is public domain and the mtcelledit library is gpl3.  With mtpixel statically linked, the binary is <100kb (only a few kb when dynamically linked) and the only other dependencies are libpng, libjpeg and libgif (and freetype with the official mtpixel, but I didn't need the text support, so I commented out the freetype bits in the static build)

feel free to modify for your own needs:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <mtpixel.h> 

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){ 
int i=0,height=0,width=0,y=0; 
mtpixel_init(); 
mtImage *imglist[argc]; 
argc--; 
do{   imglist[i] = mtpixel_image_load( argv[i+1] ); 
   height+=imglist[i]->height; 
   if (imglist[i]->width > width) width=imglist[i]->width; 
} while (++i < argc); 
imglist[argc]=mtpixel_image_new_rgb(width,height); 
imglist[argc]->palette.trans=0; 
i=0; 
do{   if (imglist[i]->type == MTPIXEL_IMAGE_INDEXED) 
      mtpixel_image_paste(imglist[argc],mtpixel_image_to_rgb(imglist[i]),mtpixel_brush_new(),0 ,y); 
   else mtpixel_image_paste(imglist[argc],imglist[i],mtpixel_brush_new(),0 ,y); 
   printf("name=%s;width=%d;height=%d;y_offset=%d\n",argv[i+1],imglist[i]->height,imglist[i]->width,y); 
   y+=imglist[i]->height; 
   mtpixel_image_destroy( imglist[i] ); 
}while (++i < argc); 
   mtpixel_image_save( imglist[argc], "sprite.png", MTPIXEL_FILE_TYPE_PNG, 5 ); 
mtpixel_quit(); 
return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net, check out http://www.RequestReduce.com. It not only creates the sprite file automatically, but it does it on the fly through an HttpModule along with merging and minifying all CSS. It lso optimizes the sprite image using quantization and lossless compression and it handles the serving of the generated files using ETags and Expires headers to ensure optimal browser caching. The setup is trivial involving just a simple web.config change. See my [blog post](http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2011/09/10/Adopt-RequestReduce-and-see-immediate-Yslow-and-Google-Page-Speed-score-improvements-not-to-mention-a-faster-site!.aspx) about its adoption by the Microsoft Visual Studio and MSDN Samples gallery.

Answer (score 0):

i recently find this tools : SpriteRight
http://spriterightapp.com/

*SpriteRight is a CSS spritesheet generator for the Mac that lets you import your existing images or stylesheets. Make your sites load faster, cut bandwidth costs and save time. SpriteRight even generates CSS code on the fly.*

Comment: Worth noting, this is not a free or open source app but fairly priced at $4.99. It's well built and does good PNG compression, more functionality than the above "Sprite Master Web".

Comment: And it's mac only aswell.