# Software/Plugin for css sprite generation

Tags: plugins, css-sprites

does anyone know if there exists any offline software or plugin(dreamweaver, etc) to generate a css sprite. That is: merging images and generating the css rules.

I know there is a post here: [Tools to make CSS sprites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527336/tools-to-make-css-sprites)

but all of those are online generation tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a Ruby library that can generate sprite images and CSS rules, which I have not fully published yet (I'm wanting to Add more features, such as CSS rewriting, so I'm waiting).

Not wanting to spam, add a comment and I'll send you the link.

As for dreamweaver plugins or desktop applications, none I am aware of.

Comment: I have no experience of ruby, but could I run it on localhost and get the functionality from it?

Comment: Yes.  http://github.com/ckwalsh/RubySprites/ is the package, my email is in the README.  You will need ruby ("sudo apt-get install ruby") and the GD or rmagick gems ("sudo apt-get install gem; sudo gem install gd2").  THe script you need is in the examples directory.  I haven't cleaned it yet (aka, it's not the most intuitive at the moment, and definitely needs documentation) but my email is in the README, feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 2):

There is a pure ruby library to generate css sprites.  that means no dependancy on rmagic or other libraries.

http://github.com/aberant/spittle