# Stick multiple images together

Tags: image

Is there a program which lets you dump an image and then you can put all the images you dumped into one image? I want to know this so I can build my tileset faster....

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on Linux, OS X, or Windows there is a great command line image manipulation tool called [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).  Included in it is the [`montage`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) utility that takes a bunch of images and tiles them together, saving them in one file.  The most basic command form is:

```
montage input1.png input2.png input3.png input4.png montage-output.png
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean HTML sprites, this website does it automatically: http://spriteme.org/.  Also see this Stack Overflow question: [Tools to make CSS sprites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527336/tools-to-make-css-sprites)