# Is there CSS sprites support in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css-sprites

I'm looking into using CSS sprites, but wouldn't like to invent the wheel.
Is there existing support in jQuery or jQuery UI? Or as an alternative, a well debugged jQuery plugin

Comment: What specific tasks do you want done?

Comment: Just to turn some of the images on a web application to sprites to make the page load more efficient

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527336/tools-to-make-css-sprites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using sprites depends on the amount of offset to the part of the position you want -- javascript can't access image data so how would there be such a thing?

There are some tools to help you make sprites and provide you with the base CSS however. Here's my favorite:

http://csssprites.com/

Answer (score 2):

There are some good [jquery-tool demos](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos) you can copy and then modify. They have good practices. I would start with the [tab anchor](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/anchors.htm) demo, their [stylesheet](http://static.flowplayer.org/css/tabs.css) is well written.

@Mark: The tabs demo uses [one image](http://static.flowplayer.org/img/global/tabs.png)

Comment: How is a tabs demo page relevant to CSS sprites?

Comment: There is an image used to draw and swap the tab navigation

Comment: Is it one image or multiple images?  If its multiple images its unrelated to CSS Sprites.

Comment: @Mark - [Sure looks like sprites to me](http://static.flowplayer.org/img/global/tabs.png)

Comment: Thats why I was asking.  That is sprites.

Comment: Alright, with the updated answer it makes more sense... (take back -1 and add +1)

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it all in CSS?  A la:

```
btn
{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:url(images/btnspite.png) -30px 100px;
}
btn:hover
{
background-position:-30px -150px;
}
btn:active
{
background-position:-30px -200px;
}
```

This'll get you started on actually implementing it:  http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: 4 spaces before a line will format it as code. Highlight a section and hit `ctr-k` to do this quickly.

Comment: Thanks Peter...it was pretty ugly-lookin'  :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the specific tasks you want to accomplish, which you do not specify in the OP, you might no need a plugin at all.

A possible way to use sprites with jQuery is to create a separate class for each sprite state, and then use jQuery to change the class attribute of the element showing the sprite with **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**:

```
  // Change the sprite state of an element
$(elementSelector).attr("class", spriteClassOfChoie);
```

For example here is a super simple image gallery making use of sprites and jQuery:

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2qL7G/)**

Script:

```
$(function() {

      // The sprite classes
    var sprites = ["home", "next", "prev"];

      // Which image is showing
    var showing = 0;

      // Show the first image
    $("#gallery").addClass(sprites[showing]);

      // Add a click handler to change sprite states
    $("input").click(function() { 

          // Cycle through images by making use of sprites
        $("#gallery").attr("class", sprites[(++showing % sprites.length)]);
    });
});​
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Show Next Image" />
<br/><br/>
<div id="gallery"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.home {
width:46px;
height:44px;
background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPDBk.gif') 0 0; }

.next {
width:43px;
height:44px;
background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPDBk.gif') -47px 0; }

.prev {
width:43px;
height:44px;
background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPDBk.gif') -91px 0; }
```