# Looking for a good Image Sprite generator tool

Tags: generator, css-sprites, sprite

I looking for a decent Image sprite generator. I tried http://spritegen.website-performance.org/ but it's not "smart" enough to handle multiple image dimensions and merge them with few blank spaces between images.

Any suggestions???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tools to make CSS sprites?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527336/tools-to-make-css-sprites)

Comment: I assume this is for css purposes.

Comment: To me, python glue http://glue.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html is the best and you can automate a lot of things too as part of your build process.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[ZeroSprites](http://zerosprites.com/) is a CSS sprites generator aimed at area minimization using VLSI floorplaning algorithms. It can generate tighter sprites sheet than [Sprite Generator](http://spritegenerator.codeplex.com/) and [Spritemapper](http://yostudios.github.com/Spritemapper/).

Comment: Thanks a lot clyfish, ZeroSprites was exactly what I was looking for. Great tool!

Comment: ZeroSprites does a great job. Besides optimizing image layout it allows multiple image upload, which is great when you have a lot of images.

Comment: any tool which doesn't let you choose the output file format and quality is not good at all.

Comment: PNG is a lossless format, so you can convert the output to other format yourself.

Comment: only works with PNGs, not really useful...

Answer (score 18):

I have used them all and [Sprite Cow](http://www.spritecow.com) is by far the best.

**Update:** There's a really cool new tool called [SpritePad](http://spritepad.wearekiss.com). It's an even better solution.

Comment: http://spritepad.wearekiss.com/ is great!

Comment: too bad you gotta pay money to use the auto-align feature...

Answer (score 3):

I use [csssprites.com](http://csssprites.com/). Its interface is a little rudimentary, but it has some good options for getting it just right, and has worked well for me.

Comment: I saw that one too, didn't like it either :P

Comment: What don't you like about it? Perhaps if you put in your requirements (and more details in general about what you're looking for), you'll get a better response.

Answer (score 3):

I created a CSS Image Sprite Generator on my website that you may find useful.  It's simple but does the job, check it out at: http://jstiles.com/Applications/CSS-Image-Sprite-Generator. And if there are any specific options/updates you want - I may be able to code them in for you; just contact me through my website, thanks.

Comment: lol @ Comic Sans on your website :-)

Comment: Doesn't work when I try to upload a 800+kb zip though for my title animation hahaha :P

Comment: You have error reporting enabled and raw PHP errors are displayed rather than being logged / custom error messages displayed. This is bad practice for a live site.