# Merge a lot of images with PHP GD (imagecopymerge) in a good time

Tags: php, image

So, I need to merge some images ( 36 or 48 ) images to another image ([image] );

The resolution of this is 4800x4800 pixels. So each square will have 695x695; I currently came up with this solution:

```
$i = 1;
        $x = 140; $y = 140;
        foreach($files as $file):
            if($i > 1) $template = 'test.png'; 
            else $template = 'templates/24x24-TEMPLATE.png';
            $this->save_image($file,'templates/temp.jpg');
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg('templates/temp.jpg');
            $src2 = imagecreatetruecolor(695,695);
            imagecopyresampled($src2, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 695, 695, 612, 612);
            imagejpeg($src2,'templates/temp.jpg');
            imagedestroy($src2);
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg('templates/temp.jpg');
            $dest = imagecreatefrompng($template);
            imagealphablending($dest, false);
            imagesavealpha($dest, true);
            imagealphablending($src, false);
            imagesavealpha($src, true);
            imagecopymerge($dest, $src, $x, $y, 0, 0, 695, 695, 100); //have to play with these numbers for it to work for you, etc.
            imagepng($dest,'test.png');
            /* Destroy the images to free up space */
            imagedestroy($dest);
            imagedestroy($src);
            $x = $x + 695 + 65;
            if($i % 6 == 0):
                $y = $y + 695 + 65;
                $x = 140;
            endif;
            $i++;
        endforeach;
```

witch downloads the file to be put onto the square, merges it with the squares, and does that for all the images until all squares are filled. But that code, for 20 images it takes up to 5 minutes! I would need something that can run under 30 seconds to fill up the squares with the images and then generate a single file PDF.

Is there anyway to improve this? Or is there any other way to do this faster and better?

Comment: have you tried wkhtmltopdf, you will show images in html, after that call wkhtmltopdf

Comment: I actually don't need to do that. I will need to process the images in backend, because I don't want to have a large document like the 4800x4800 in a web page;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume by "in a good time" you mean quickly and efficiently.

Then the answer is probably to do it outside of PHP. Even though the data is mostly held in custom data structures using the GD extension there's still a lot of overhead in the PHP code. There are [lots of tools for merging images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968702/looking-for-a-good-image-sprite-generator-tool) for the purpose of generating CSS sprites - however they don't all provide control over the layout of the images. You could write your own using GD and C.

But why bother? If you utlimately want the output as a PDF, why not just write the individual images directly into the PDF?

Comment: yeah. right. I was tired last night and I complicated myself with the image generation. I should just merge everything into the PDF from te begining. Oh