# how to minify images in asp.net 45?

Tags: asp.net

I want to minify images folder which is used in my css and also on the Home page (master page).
Is it possible to minify images same as CSS and js in asp.net ?

Thanks
Rajesh

Comment: open all images in any image editor, and change resolution to you needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Sprite and Image Optimization package on [codeplex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/65787).

What you want is to create an image sprite (merging all the images into one). And then letting that adjust your css.  This will reduce the number of calls made to the server to retrieve images and should reduce the overall size of the image (depending on optimisation).

Looks like Scott Hanselman had a [post about this package a little while ago](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek1ASPNETSpriteAndImageOptimization.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can't really minify images, but you can bundle several images into a single sprite (search online for a tutorial, or [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968702/looking-for-a-good-image-sprite-generator-tool)).

You can also compress images before uploading them to your site using [PNGGauntlet](http://pnggauntlet.com/) or similar.