# debugging a slow site -> long delay between connection and data sending

Tags: apache, optimization, time, web, loading

i ran a test from pingdom tools to check the loading time of my website... the result is that i have a lot of files that, in spite of being very small (5kB), take a lot of time (1 second or more) to load because there is a *big* delay between the beginning of the connection and the beginning of data downloading (in pingdom tools, this results in a very large green bar).

Have a look at this for example: http://tools.pingdom.com/default.asp?url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.giochigratis-online.net%2f&id=5691308

How can i lower the "green bar" time? Is this an apache problem (like, i dont know, the number of max. parallel connections, or something similar...), or an hardware problem? Cpu-limited, bandwith-limited, or what else?

I see that many other websites have very little green bars... how do they reduce the delay between the connection and the real data sending?

Thanks!

ps.: the site is made with drupal. Homepage generation takes about 700ms

pps.: i tested 3 other websites on the same server: same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be the problem with max no. of parallel connections as you mentioned - either on server or client side. For instance, Firefox has default of `network.http.max-connections-per-server` = 15 (see [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries#Network.)) while you have >70 files to be downloaded in your domain and next 40 from Facebook.

You can reduce number of loaded images by generating [sprites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527336/tools-to-make-css-sprites) i.e. the image consisting of multiple small images, and then using CSS to diplay them properly in places that you want. This is widely used e.g. by Google - see http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo83.png